# Read one file by thread with libcurl in C

Tags: c, multithreading, http, libcurl

I want to read multiple online files with libcurl (and especially using functions defined in [fopen.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html)) . For this, I want to use multiple threads but only one thread for each files. My code works fine for one URL, but gives segmentation fault, or core dumped for more than one file.

Here is my code :

```
void * extract_file(void * filename) 
{
    URL_FILE *handle;
    int err;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error while initializing libcurl.\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   CURLcode curlcode = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, true);

   char *file = (char *) filename;

   handle = url_fopen(file, "rb");
   if(handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening %s.\n", file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    uint64_t n;
    bool empty = true;
    while(url_fread(&n, sizeof(uint64_t), 1, handle) != 0) {
        empty = false;
        sem_wait(&empty1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        push(&buffer1, n);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&full1);
    }

    err = url_fclose(handle);
    if(err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while closing %s.\n", file);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    debug_printf("Leaving extract_file.\n");

    if(empty) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s is either empty or non-existing.\n", file);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

NOTE : I dropped some unimportant details of my code.

Each "reader" thread starts this function with the usual pthread_create.
So I have two questions :
1) Why can't I read more than one online file at a time with this code without causing segmentation fault?
2) Why the handle == NULL condition isn't true when file is either a non-existing local file or a non-existing online file? (this is why I have to use the bool empty variable).

Also note that I used curl_global_init() before starting any thread.

Thank by advance.

EDIT : my GDB output when segmentation fault occurs :

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff2924700 (LWP 3280)]
0x00007ffff7684f3a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
```

Comment: Regarding point 2, it should be, but such problems can be caused by the same error which gives you the segfault. Use your debugger to search the location, we can´t without the full code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

libCurl doens't allow using the same handle in different threads (see [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/features.html), in section about thread-safety), it causes errors. So we can't use [fopen.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html) directly to read multiples files in different threads. We have to modify the global variable `multi_handle` by adding `__thread`, then it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think from your code, it is related to `curl_easy_init()` calling `curl_global_init()` because your code does not call it itself.

Curl doc at this [page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html) says:

> If you did not already call curl_global_init, curl_easy_init does it
>   automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since
>   curl_global_init is not thread-safe, and it may result in resource
>   problems because there is no corresponding cleanup.

So, try calling `curl_global_init()`before `curl_easy_init()`in your code.

Comment: `Also note that I used curl_global_init() before starting any thread.`